# Print CPLEX current feasible solution every 60 seconds on C# (Concert technology)

Tags: c#, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I want to solve the MILP problem with CPLEX-C#. My question is that how can I get (print) the current feasible solution every 60 seconds. In other words, I am assigning the time limit of 5 minutes and I want to see the current feasible solution every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the example MIPex4.cs in CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\examples\src\cs

where you will see

```
cplex.Use(new LogCallback(lp.NumVars, -100000, lastObjVal));
```

Comment: Just to add to Alex's answer, the callback will probably be called very many times from CPLEX. so you probably need a timer in your callback so that the real body of the callback only gets called once a suitable time has elapsed from when it last got called.